# How to make a bilingual front-end post using the plugin WP User Frontend and Polylang or qTranslate?

Tags: posts, front-end, multi-language

I'm implementing a bilingual blog site (English and Japanese). It contains front-end user posting and user registration. So, I used [WP User Frontend](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend). For multilingual content, I tried [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/i) and [Polylang](http://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/).

**Polylang** is one language per post. **qTranslate** is all languages in a single post. Both are nice and language-selection for posting is implemented in the Admin.

I could have created a basic front-end posting form according to [the installation guide of WP User Frontend](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/installation/). I have facing two problems:

1. Which one is better for front-end user posting - **Polylang** or **qTranslate**?
2. How can I implement a language selection entry for front-end user posting?

**[UPDATE]**
I found the two functions:

- `WPUF_Add_Post->submit_post()` in `wp-user-front-end/wpuf-add-post.php`
- `PLL_Admin_Filters_Post->save_post()` in `polylang/admin/admin-filters-post.php`.

I could add a custom field "Language" for the fontend posting form of **WP User Frontend** and then I could make those two functions running in combination. I'm new to wordpress and I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: No one who has ever encountered this kind of problem?

Comment: Did you got any solutions?